# Big O and Big Omega of worst-case time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I've been taking an algorithm class and so far, the worst-case time complexity for an algorithm all have the same (tight) Big O and Big Omega. Can someone give an example where the two differ? Or explain the importance of these two terms when analyzing the worst-case of an algorithm. I'm struggling to find the point of both of them when it's always the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

These concepts can be quite confusing.

*O*, *Ω* and *Θ* aren't actually tied to worst, best and average time complexities. They just describe relations between functions, or complexity classes.

It is not quite correct to say O describes worst-case, Ω describes best case and Θ describes average. Rather, O describes an upper-bound, Ω a lower bound and Θ describes both at once.

For instance, it is perfectly correct to say that Quicksort has an average time complexity of *O(n log n)* and a worst-case complexity of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. What is meant is that they are no higher than these complexities.

In short:

- *f(n) = O(g(n))* means *f(n)* is bounded above by *g(n)*. Analogous to **≤**.
- *f(n) = Ω(g(n))* means *f(n)* is bounded below by *g(n)*. Analogous to **≥**.
- *f(n) = Θ(g(n))* means *f(n)* is bounded both above and below by *g(n)*. Analogous to **=**.

In practice you often see big-O used when big-Θ could have been more informative. In general, when you publish a new algorithm and you want to claim that it is asymptotically faster than others, you might just say that it has a worst-case time complexity of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* when the previously known fastest algorithm was e.g. *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*. Everyone then understands that you have found an asymptotically faster algorithm. Maybe it turns out that your algorithm is actually *O(n<sup>1.99</sup>)* but it was easier to prove that it was *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Then it is a correct statement because *n<sup>1.99</sup> = O(n<sup>2</sup>)* but it would not have held true for Θ.

And finally, since you wanted an example of where *O* and *Ω* might differ: Quicksort has average time complexity *O(n log n)*. But it is also correct to say it has average time complexity *O(n<sup>100</sup>)* because

*n log n = O(n<sup>100</sup>)*.

Similarly, we can say it is *Ω(1)* because it is definitely higher or equal to constant-time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still don't quite get the concept. In your example of the average case of quicksort, if it has a tight upper bound of O(n lg n) then can I say that it has a tight lower bound of n lg n? If so, when do they actually differ? My question is basically if I can find a tight upper bound of some function then surely it has the same tight lower bound?

Comment: @frank If you have a function f(x) then yes, it has both an upper bound of f(x) and a lower bound of f(x). So f(x) = Θ(f(x)). But you use all these tools depending on what you want to say, like you use ≤, ≥ and =. In addition, you don't always know how a function behaves on every point (consider periodic functions). You might know it is bounded above, but don't know exactly (or maybe don't care) if it is bounded below by the same function or by something else.

Answer (score 1):

Consider computing the Discrete Fourier Transform of a signal of length N, using the factorization trick: instead of applying a transform of length n.m, with a cost Θ(n.m.N), you decompose in a tranform of length n followed by one of length m, giving the total cost Θ((n+m).N). If N is a prime, the complexity is N²; if N is a power of 2, the complexity is N.Lg(N). As these are the extreme cases, we have O(N²) and Ω(N.Lg(N)).

---

Note: the computations do not depend on the particular sample values, so the given costs are simultaneously best case and worst case for a given N.

---

Below, the curve of the sum of prime factors (with their multiplicity):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I understand. So in this case, where the best-case/worst-case is directly related to length of N, and not the configuration of the input, we can have different upper and lower bounds? Am I right in my assumption or am I completely off?

Comment: @frank: what do you call "my assumption" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 measures of time complexity:

- Big O: worst case complexity
- Big theta (Θ): average case complexity (usually when people say big O, they mean big theta)
- Big omega (Ω): best case complexity

Big O >= Big theta >= Big omega

Take quicksort, for example. It will *always* take at least `n log n`, where the input is `n` elements long, so that is the lower bound. It will *always* take at most `n^2`, so that is the upper bound. It will *usually* take `n log n`, so that is the average case.

So for quicksort, the Big O is `O(n^2)`, Big theta is `Θ(n log n)`, and Big omega is `Ω(n log n)`.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the algorithms that we offer classes are generally going to be well-understood algorithms that we can make very precise behavior about.  And most will have big-O and big-Omega the same.  In fact the fact that they ARE so often the same is why people informally talk about big-O when they really mean big-Theta.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72998800/585411 offered an excellent example of an important algorithm whose performance jumps around so much depending on `n` that big-O and big-Omega are very different.  But understanding how the [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) works will take some effort.  I therefore want to offer a very easy to understand algorithm which has the same property.

Problem, given `n` find the next prime.  Our algorithm in pseudocode will be:

```
let k = n
let isPrime = true
while not isPrime:
    k++
    isPrime = true
    for i in range(2, sqrt(k)):
        if 0 == k % 2:
            isPrime = false
            break
return k
```

In other words, "Search until we find a number that we prove is prime through trial division."  This isn't a particularly efficient algorithm, but it is easy to understand.

The best performance is if the next number is prime.  Then this runs in `Ω(sqrt(n))`.  (That requires that the modulo operation is `Ω(1)`.  This is true for 64 bit integers but is a big whopping lie for big integer math.  I'm also making it a function of `n` instead of the number of bits needed to represent `n`.  The latter is more usual in analyzing number theory algorithms.)

But what is the worst performance?  Well, that is a hard number theory problem.  Seriously, start with [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) and dig in.  But if we just want a limit, we can use Bertrand's postulate to say `O(n sqrt(n))`.  If the Riemann hypothesis is true, we could prove `O(n log(n))`.

So here we get big-O and big-Omega very different, and (despite the code being simple) we still can't put a precise bound on the big-O.

In your course they'll focus on relatively simple algorithms that are easy to analyze.  And I think your implicit point is very good that we should offer examples of algorithms whose performance is all over the map, and which are hard to analyze.  Like this one.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example. From what I understand, there is a distinction between best and worst-case complexity for an algorithm. Is this example, when the next number is prime is describing the best-case and it runs in Omega(sqrt(n)). In this same case, where the next number is a prime as well, does it have big O(sqrt(n))?

Comment: @frank Big-O describes a function's growth.  The complexity of this algorithm depends on `n`, bounces around, and is emphatically NOT described by `O(sqrt(n))`.  Attempting to say "big-O but only for `n` that I like" will confuse your understanding of big-O, and guarantee that others don't know what you mean either.

Comment: When my lecturer was explaining this concept, she used insertion Sort as an example. She said that when n is reverse-sorted, it has Big-O(n^2). Is this not the same as defining n as I like? Where is the boundary of how much I can change my input to fit the best/worst case? Basically, I don't get how my lecturer can change the input to justify that reverse-sorting the list was the worst-case but for functions like these, it doesn't make much sense to change the input so that the next number is prime and perform Big-O analysis on that. Sorry if this is confusing, I'm just extremely confused.

Comment: @frank We are describing the algorithm in terms of a function of "size of the input".  If the input is an array of fixed length, then using the length of the array is a reasonable input.  I'm using the number itself as size of input.  That said, in many ways the example that Yves Daoust gave is better than mine.  (Not the least being, it looks like the examples you've used.)